# Why my hosts file is not saving/resetting after editing it?

Tags: hosts

I need to add `#` before the command line (so I can login into my google account which is a common problem).

I rooted my device (I'm using a huawei P8) and tried using total commander and root explorer, both no success. With root explorer, I used `mount r/w` in the `etc` folder. Basically, after editing the hosts file and restart the device, the file looks like it didn't change or it resetted. Even before restart the device I checked the file again (because I suspected that it just didn't save or something) and I saw the file didn't change.

Any help would be really helpful. If any info is needed, just say it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try changing r/w to system folder as the [answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/155035/edit-hosts-file-from-terminal-ide-with-root-accessed) by lzzy.