# Edit hosts file from terminal IDE with root accessed

Tags: root-access, terminal, hosts

My terminal IDE accessed root but cannot edit hosts file.

```
root@172.16.0.151:/system/etc #vim hosts
```

But vim just opens hosts file as readonly. Where do I missed here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've missed that the `/system` file system is *mounted read-only.*

```
mount -o remount,rw /system
cd /system/etc
vim hosts
# edit, save, then make /system read-only again:
mount -o remount,ro /system
```